# When did product.permalink attribute became deprecated?

Tags: spree

I'm using spree version 2.3.1, and an error showing **undefined method `permalink' for Spree::Product**
appears from code i was using in a smaller version of spree, can anyone point out in wish version spree stopped using this attribute

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From version 2.3.0 Spree started using friendly_id gem instead of custom permalink generation code. You can find the commit that switched to friendly_id [here](https://github.com/spree/spree/commit/d4d955017102f31980cc3cf3c0ca7ad9f5b053bd).

Comment: The main problem is that i'm building an extension and i need to provide support for other versions, and my code is filled with **find_by_permalink**, now i'll create a branch for 2-3 and fix them all